# me pueden dar una pequeña explicación?

Tags: javascript

estaba resolviendo uno de los retos de adventjs y como soy un poco nuevo no podía resolverlos, hasta este punto... logré resolverlo (con un poquito de ayuda), pero me quedo una duda y es que: que hace esa pequeña linea de código dentro de map? se lo que me devuelve, pero quiero saber que procedimiento hace para darme el resultado, me podrían explicar?

```
function fixFiles(files) {
 var newFile = []
 return files.map(file=>{
        newFile[file]= newFile[file] + 1 || 0;})
```

Comment: Bienvenido, es muy importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask],y no olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio,  saludos.

Comment: Pon en el título de la pregunta qué es lo que no estás (o no estabas) comprendiendo. La pregunta y sus respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad. Otras personas con un problema similar no podrán encontrar esta pregunta si se titula así como está actualmente. Lee [ask].

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida e indicarme el recorrido de bienvenida ya se ahora como va la pagina. Ahora se como formular mi pregunta para no solo ayudarme a mi sino a futuros entusiastas, pero que pondría al reescribir esta preguntando?, nose como se le denomina a esa pequeña linea de codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devuelve `0` en caso de que `newFile[file]+1` se evalue como `false` o `undefined`

```
function fixFiles(files) {
 var newFile = []
 return files.map(file=>{
        newFile[file]= newFile[file] + 1 || 0;})
```

Pero no hace nada.

```js
function fixFiles(files) {
  var newFile = []
  return files.map(file => {
    newFile[file] = newFile[file] + 1 || 0;
  })

}



console.log(fixFiles(['q']))
```

Debería ser:

```js
function fixFiles(files) {
  var newFile = []
  return files.map(file => {
    return file + 1 || 0;
  })
}



console.log(fixFiles(['q', undefined]))
```

Comment: muchas, esa explicacion me hizo comprender mejor esa linea de codigo, y si no hace nada ya que no puse todo el codigo, MUCHAS GRACIAS POR TU TIEMPO :)